# Run remote PowerShell Office uninstallation script

Tags: powershell, windows-update

KB2956128 is causing headache for users in my network. I do not run WSUS in this environment so I was going to employ PS script to take care of uninstallation.
By all means the script below should work

```powershell
$comp = 'PC03'
$scrblock = 
{
$TitlePattern = 'KB2956128'

$Session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session

$Collection = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$Installer = $Session.CreateUpdateInstaller()
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()) | 
    Where-Object { $_.Title -match $TitlePattern } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Verbose "Found update history entry $($_.Title)"
        $SearchResult = $Searcher.Search("UpdateID='$($_.UpdateIdentity.UpdateID)' and RevisionNumber=$($_.UpdateIdentity.RevisionNumber)")
        Write-Verbose "Found $($SearchResult.Updates.Count) update entries"
        if ($SearchResult.Updates.Count -gt 0) {
            $Installer.Updates = $SearchResult.Updates
            $Installer.Uninstall()
            $Installer | Select-Object -Property ResultCode, RebootRequired, Exception
            # result codes: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720442(WS.10).aspx
        }
    }
}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock $scrblock -Credential 'myDomain\administrator'
```

Instead I get this error

```powershell
Exception calling "CreateUpdateInstaller" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
    + PSComputerName        : PC03

Exception calling "QueryHistory" with "2" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80240007"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
    + PSComputerName        : PC03
```

I don't quite understand why the access is denied. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that the [ComObject does not allow the CreateUpdateInstaller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386863(v=vs.85).aspx) to be called remotely. You can only do this locally, not over sessions or any other remoting. You can however use psexec to remotely execute your script as system.